# Android GoogleDrive insert.execute() raising IOException - how can I get more information on the error?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to my GoogleDrive , but I get an IOException raised , and I cannot find why ? what's wrong ? what should modify ?
credentials,  filepath, filename , filetype ( text/csv) are correct... the parent_id folderID is fine...
and obviously I tested before if connected to internet... but no way , I always get this IOException on line :  file = insert.execute()  (I executed a debugger run...)

```
      private File uploadFile(boolean useDirectUpload) throws IOException {
        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(mFileUri.getPath());

        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(mFolderId)));
        fileMetadata.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("text/csv", new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileContent)));
        mediaContent.setLength(fileContent.length());

        Drive.Files.Insert insert = mService.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
        MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
        uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(useDirectUpload);
        uploader.setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);
        uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
        File file = insert.execute();
        //return insert.execute();
        return file;
  }
```

Comment: I can now get the stack trace , adding Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));  however as frequently the error stated :   { "code": 404, "errors": [{"domain": "global","message": "File not found: ","reason": "notFound" } ],"message": "File not found: "}  is not informative AT ALL...  Google API doc:  Suggested action: Report to users that they do not have read access to the file or that the file does not exist. Tell them that they should ask the owner for permission to the file. ... which file ? the existing  one I am uploading or the existing parent folder ?

Answer (score 1):

the parentID  'mFolderID' was null.. (that's give sense to the message wo any id..)
I modified my design ... previously  using 2 threads with WeakReference...  one for getting the folderID ( and setting the private static String mFolderId) and another one for uploading (using mFolderID) ... but using WeakReference, mFolderId was set to null for this new thread

now I am using only one thread to get the folderID and upload file in it...

```
    private void uploadFileInSwinglogFolder() {
    mUploadFileInSwinglogFolderThread = new UploadFileInSwinglogFolderThread(UploadActivity.this);
    mUploadFileInSwinglogFolderThread.start();      
}

// static inner classes don't hold implicit references to their
// enclosing class, so the Activity instance won't be leaked across configuration change    
private static class UploadFileInSwinglogFolderThread extends Thread {
    private final WeakReference<UploadActivity> mActivity;

    public UploadFileInSwinglogFolderThread(UploadActivity activity) {
      mActivity = new WeakReference<UploadActivity>(activity);
    }

    private boolean mRunning = false;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        UploadActivity activity = mActivity.get();
        mRunning = true;
        while (mRunning) {
            mResultList = new ArrayList<File>();
            mIOException = false;
            mFolderId = null;
            Files f1 = mService.files();
            Files.List request = null;
                try  {
                    request = f1.list();
                    // searching for named folder at root level
                    String aQuery = "'root' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title='"+ mFolderName + "'";
                    request.setQ(aQuery);                       
                    FileList fileList = request.execute();
                    mResultList.addAll(fileList.getItems());
                    request.setPageToken(fileList.getNextPageToken());
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    activity.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "STACKTRACE");
                    Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    mIOException = true;
                    Message msg = activity.mHandler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("msgKey", UploadActivity.IO_EXCEPTION);
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    activity.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                } finally {
                    if (mResultList.size() == 0) {
                        Message msg = activity.mHandler.obtainMessage();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("msgKey", UploadActivity.NO_SWIMLOGS_FOLDER);
                        msg.setData(bundle);
                        activity.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    } else {
                        // Got the parent folderID in googleDrive
                        mFolderId =  mResultList.get(0).getId();
                        File file = null;
                        try {
                            java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(mFileUri.getPath());
                            //FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", fileContent);
                            InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("text/csv", new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileContent)));
                            mediaContent.setLength(fileContent.length());

                            File body = new File();
                            body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());                   
                            body.setMimeType("text/csv");
                            Log.d(TAG, "mFolderID: " + mFolderId);
                            body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(mFolderId)));

                            Drive.Files.Insert insert = mService.files().insert(body, mediaContent);

                            MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
                            uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
                            uploader.setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);
```

// TODO set progress listener                               //uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());

```
                            file = insert.execute();                                
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "IOException in uploading file code: ");
                            Log.e(TAG, "STACKTRACE");
                            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                            Message msg = activity.mHandler.obtainMessage();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putInt("msgKey", UploadActivity.IO_EXCEPTION);
                            msg.setData(bundle);
                            activity.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                        } finally {
                            Log.d(TAG, "end try - finally block ");
                            if ( file != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Uploading file done: " + file.getTitle());
                                Log.d(TAG, "UploadActivity - thread - file uploaded");
                                Message msg = activity.mHandler.obtainMessage();
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putInt("msgKey", UploadActivity.SWIMLOG_UPLOADED);
                                msg.setData(bundle);
                                activity.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);                                 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    mRunning = false;
                }
        }
    }
    public void close() {
        mRunning = false;
    }
}
```